# Need help subrouting in Express and Mongo

Tags: mongodb, express

I'm trying to make subroutes in express, using mongo as my database but I keep getting this error when I try to access 'book/shelf' and 'book/number' (regardless of the number I use) routes:

'Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed'

Everything else seems to be working fine. I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thank you

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router ();
const shelf = require ('./shelf');

// Book Model
const Book = require ('../models/Book');

router.use ('/shelf', shelf);

router.get ('/:number', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send ('Book #' + req.params.number);
});

// Test route
router.get ('/test', (req, res) => res.json ({msg: 'Hello'}));

// GET ROUTE: Book
router.get ('/', function (req, res, next) {
  Book.find (null, function (err, book) {
    res.json ({
      confirmation: 'Here are the books',
      result: book,
    });
  });
});


// Add Books
router.post ('/add', (req, res) => {
  const booktitle = req.body.booktitle;
  const author = req.body.author;
  const publisher = req.body.publisher;
  const genre = req.body.genre;

  const newBook = new Book ({
    booktitle,
    author,
    publisher,
    genre,
  });

  newBook
    .save ()
    .then (() => res.json ('Book added!'))
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});

// GET Request, Book by id
router.get ('/:bookId', (req, res) => {
  Book.findById (req.params.bookId)
    .then (book => res.json (book))
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});

// Delete Book
router.delete ('/:bookId', (req, res) => {
  Book.findByIdAndDelete (req.params.bookId)
    .then (() => res.json ('Book deleted.'))
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});

// Update Book
router.post ('/update/:bookId', (req, res) => {
  Book.findById (req.params.bookId)
    .then (book => {
      book.booktitle = req.body.booktitle;
      book.author = req.body.author;
      book.publisher = req.body.publisher;
      book.genre = req.body.genre;

      book
        .save ()
        .then (() => res.json ('Book updated!'))
        .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
    })
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});


module.exports = router;
```

**EDIT: Adding the shelf route:**

```
const express = require ('express');
const router = express.Router ();

// Shelf model
const Shelf = require ('../models/Shelf');

// Get route
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      Shelf.find()
      .then(shelf => res.json(shelf))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  });

// ADD Shelf ROUTE
router.post ('/add', (req, res) => {

  const shelf = req.body.shelf;
  const newShelf = new Shelf ({
  shelf,
});

  newShelf
    .save ()
    .then (() => res.json ('Shelf added!'))
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});

// Find Shelf by Id
router.get ('/:shelfId', (req, res) => {
  Shelf.findById (req.params.shelfId)
    .then (shelf => res.json (shelf))
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});

// Delete Shelf
router.delete ('/:shelfId', (req, res) => {
  Shelf.findByIdAndDelete ({shelf: req.params.shelfId})
    .then (() => res.json ('shelf deleted.'))
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});

// Update Shelf
router.post ('/update/:shelfId', (req, res) => {
  Shelf.findById (req.params.shelfId)
    .then (shelf => {
      shelf.shelf = req.body.shelf;

      shelf
        .save ()
        .then (() => res.json ('Shelf has been updated!'))
        .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
    })
    .catch (err => res.status (400).json ('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: can you post the code of your shelf file?

Comment: What exact URL fails?  And, please show the Express code that hooks up your book router.  Off the top of my head, it looks like you have conflicting routes.  If you have `/book/:bookID`, then that will not allow `/book/anythingelse` in any subsequent routes because those will all match `/book/:bookID` first.